# Show text from input after submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hy!

I want to show the text from the input after the submit on the beginning of the page

My Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
@{
    if (ViewData["uname"]!=null )
    {
            <div>
            Username: @ViewData["uname"] //The Text from the input should be displayed here after submit
            @Session["uname"] = @ViewData["uname"]
            </div>
    }
}
<h2>Login</h2>
<h4>Username:</h4>
<input type="text" name="uname" value="" /> //Input
<button />
```

When i press the button nothing occurs. The Text from the input should appear abouth. The standard type of the button is submit.

Comment: can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? Where do you want the text to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Login"; 
} 
@{ 
    if (ViewData["uname"]!=null ) 
    { 
            <div> 
            Username: @ViewData["uname"] 
            @Session["uname"] = @ViewData["uname"] 
            </div> 
    } 
} 
<h2>Login</h2> 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h4>Username:</h4> 
    <input type="text" name="uname" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

This uses an HtmlHelper to create the `<form />` tags surrounding, so on submit it should post.

Comment: @test123123 do you have a POST (with attribute `[HttpPost]`) action in the corresponding controller to handle this post?

Comment: Controller: public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /User/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }